# Windows 10 drives pool questions (replace, upgrade)

Tags: windows, raid, storage-pool

i have some questions about Windows 10 pool.

Let's suppose i have 4 disks ot 4TB and i choose the parity option. This means Window will simulate a RAID 6? Because in my test i see 8TB as drive space.
Considering is a Windows 10 pro, can i shutdown the PC without any problem or it must stay running for let pool work?

If one drive fail, i should wait Windows remove the drive from pool, but i need to remove the drive from the case while the PC is running or i can shutdown, replace the drive, turn on the PC?

What happening if i change all the drives with a different size? For example 6TB instead of 4TB? Pool will still be 4TB or automatically increase to 6TB?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Have you looked through [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/storage-spaces-fault-tolerance) and [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/drive-symmetry-considerations) docs page? ("Storage Spaces Direct" in Windows Server is roughly like Storage Spaces in Windows 10.)

Comment: @user1686 Yes, i did already, but still not 100% about the first question and definitely no clue about the last 2 questions.

Comment: What do you mean by "it must stay running for let pool work"? Your 2nd question is about a feature usually called "hotswap". Whether this is supported or not depends on hardware and its drivers.

Comment: @gronostaj I'm actually using Windows 10 Storage Pool, is a software tool without any extra hardware. That's why i'm asking if i can replace an hard drive while the PC is off, considering is a Home PC, with a normal Windows 10 and no extra hardware such as RAID controller or SATA switches.

Comment: Your motherboard is the hardware. Or strictly speaking the SATA controller on it.